# How to get these numbers from var stocks while scraping web?

Tags: javascript, python

```
<form class="col-xs-12"> <script type="text/javascript">

var stocks = {
  "938975": true,
  "938977": true,
  "938979": true,
  "938981": true,
  "938983": true,
  "938985": true,
  "938987": false,
  "938989": true,
  "938991": true,
  "938993": true,
  "938995": true,
  "938997": false,
  "938999": true,
  "939001": true,
  "939003": true,
  "939005": true,
  "939007": true
};
```

How do I get and loop it, that if there is a `true` value in `var stocks` for any variable bot goes further but when there is `false` it stops?

For now I'm using something like that, hope you understand:

div = soup.find("form",("class"=="col-xs-12")).find("script",("type"=="text/javascript"

I’m doing bot in python

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: I'm kinda new to this. The problem is that it's a web, product page source and these numbers starting at 9 are product IDs that can be used for adding to cart. I want to get to var stocks, check if product is available at the moment, and if so add it to cart and proceed to checkout

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help!
Have added the code so if we have some entries at the end, even if we do not have false, they also get added. Its outside the loop and can be removed if not needed.

```js
var stocks = {"938975":true,"938977":true,"938979":true,"938981":true,"938983":true,"938985":true,"938987":false,"938989":true,"938991":true,"938993":true,"938995":true,"938997":false,"938999":true,"939001":true,"939003":true,"939005":true,"939007":true};

var arraysOfStocks = [],tempArray = [];
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(stocks)) {
  //console.log(key +":"+value);
  if(value){
     tempArray.push(key);
  } else {
     arraysOfStocks.push(tempArray);
     tempArray = [];
  }
}
arraysOfStocks.push(tempArray);
tempArray = [];

console.log(arraysOfStocks);
```

Comment: Yeah, but I', scraping a web and it's a not really what I wanted to do. I don't know "var stocks" because it changes every time I enter the website. Also it's a product and I wanna check if it's available (if it is - stocks shows "true", if not "false"). If yes - add to cart and proceed to checkout - if not retry until it will be available and still try to checkout